# Error output libdns162

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, updates, security

When I typed in following:

```
apt-cache policy libdns162
```

I receive this output:

```
libdns162:
Installed: 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.8    
Candidate: 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10
```

I get following after typing:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libdns162

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  clang-format clang-format-3.8 libclang1 libclang1-3.8 libffi-dev libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 liblldb-3.6 liblldb-3.8 libtinfo-dev libuv1 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-38 linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-40
  linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-40-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-38-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-40-generic lldb lldb-3.8 llvm-3.8 llvm-3.8-dev llvm-3.8-runtime nodejs python-lldb-3.8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdns162
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/880 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Invalid archive member header 
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libdns162_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 325831 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdns162_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
dpkg: error processing package libdns162:amd64 (--configure):
 package libdns162:amd64 is already installed and configured
Setting up libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bind9-host:
 bind9-host depends on libdns162 (= 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10); however:
  Version of libdns162:amd64 on system is 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.8.

dpkg: error processing package bind9-host (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dnsutils:
 dnsutils depends on libdns162 (= 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10); however:
  Version of libdns162:amd64 on system is 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.8.
 dnsutils depends on bind9-host | host; however:
  Package bind9-host is not configured yet.
  Package host is not installed.
  Package bind9-host which provides host is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dnsutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdns162:amd64
 bind9-host
 dnsutils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I install:

```
1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: the error you have might be related to *Corrupt packages in your local cache*, please execute the following command to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

> [man apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt-get.8.html)
>
> ```
> clean
>       clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.
>       It removes everything but the lock file from
>       /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.
> ```

---

You can upgrade `libdns162` package using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libdns162
```

Note that before performing the package upgrade you might need to execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. I edited my post with the output I got.

Comment: @OcK - happy that it helped :) Note that it easier to solve the errors you have -  when they are mentioned in the question :)